# How do I convert a value after using DATEADD with it

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd

I have a little query that strips the date from the datetime field but when I try to convert it from GMT to CST it readds the date.  Is there a better way to do this?

Location table:

```
arrival
4-6-2018 12:35:43




SELECT arrival
FROM(
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), arrival))
FROM locations
)a
```

This query will give me this result:

12:35:43

```
SELECT (DATEADD(hour,-5,arrival))
FROM(
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), arrival))
FROM locations
)a
```

4-6-2018 12:35:43

This query will give readd the date.  How can I remove the date and then do the dateadd function without it readding the date

Comment: A decent DBMS should have a `time` datatype :-) Hint: SQL Server 2008+ supports it, too: `cast(DATEADD(hour,-5,arrival) as time)`

Comment: Seeing function names I would assume you are using MS SQL. If so try casting as Time. There is also Convert function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name @CetinBasoz OP has already mentioned `sql-server` in tag.

Comment: @Sandeep originally he didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is what you are asking for:

```
SELECT Convert(Varchar(8), DATEADD(hour,-5,arrival), 108)
FROM locations;
```

Note: This is compatible with SQL server versions that doesn't have Time datatype too.

Answer (score 3):

`arrival` seems to be a DateTime, which always carries a date part. You need a `time` instead, supported by SQL Server 2008+:

```
cast(DATEADD(hour,-5,arrival) as time)
```

Answer (score 2):

To quote from [`DATEADD` (Transact-SQL) - Return Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-types):

> The return data type is the data type of the date argument, except for string literals. **The return data type for a string literal is datetime**. An error will be raised if the string literal seconds scale is more than three positions (.nnn) or contains the time zone offset part.

Emphasis my own.

As you are passing a string (`varchar`), then `DATEADD` is returning a `datetime`.

Like those in the comments have said, if you use the correct data type (`time`) this problem goes away:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, -5,CONVERT(time,Arrival))
FROM (VALUES('4-6-2018 12:35:43'),('4-6-2018 07:35:43'),('4-6-2018 03:35:43')) V(Arrival)
```